# two-sided moving average?

Tags: r

how to get two sided "moving average" that is a function that averages n numbers from right and left of a vector and gives them weights according to their distance from center value ?

I tried to use TTR but its moving averages works only from left to right and set leftmost values as NA. So I cannot use that smoothed vector as a input to smooth.spline

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the zoo package `rollmean` and `rollapply` have arguments that allow numerous variations.

```
library(zoo)
x <- seq(10)^2

# no NAs at end
rollmean(x, 3)

# NAs at ends
rollmean(x, 3, na.pad = TRUE)

# weighted mean
rollapply(zoo(x), 3, function(x) c(1, 2, 1) %*% x / 4) 

# at ends take means of less than 3 points - needs devel version
# partial= is in development and at this point must use na.rm = TRUE to use partial
source("http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/zoo/R/rollapply.R?revision=802&root=zoo")
rollapply(zoo(x), 3, mean, partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
```

EDIT:

Note that since this was written the development version of zoo was changed so that instead of writing `partial = TRUE` one writes rule = "partial" or `rule = 3`.  The problem was that as new end rules were added to the development version (there are now 3 and a 4th will be added before its released) having a separate argument for each one clutters the user interface.  Also `rule` is more consistent with `approx` in the core of R.  In fact, `rule=1` and `rule=2` will have the same meaning in `rollapply` and in `approx` (from the core of R) for better consistency and ease of use.  The parentheses around `mean` in the example below are currently required in the development version to prevent it from calling `rollmean`, where `rule="partial"` has not yet been implemented, but the need to do that will be eliminated by the time its officially released.

```
source("http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/zoo/R/rollapply.R?revision=815&root=zoo")
rollapply(zoo(x), 3, (mean), rule = "partial")
```

Comment: But why output of rollmean is always one element shorter than itput ?

Answer (score 6):

Look at the `filter()` function, and particularly the `sides` argument:

> ```
> filter                  package:stats             R Documentation
>
> Linear Filtering on a Time Series
>
> Description:
>
>      Applies linear filtering to a univariate time series or to each
>      series separately of a multivariate time series.
>
> Usage:
>
>      filter(x, filter, method = c("convolution", "recursive"),
>             sides = 2, circular = FALSE, init)
>
> Arguments:
> [...] 
>    sides: for convolution filters only. If ‘sides=1’ the filter
>           coefficients are for past values only; if ‘sides=2’ they are
>           centred around lag 0. In this case the length of the filter
>           should be odd, but if it is even, more of the filter is
>           forward in time than backward.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You could try [`kernel`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kernel.html) together with [`kernapply`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/kernapply.html) (there are some examples towards the end of the first page).