# Calculating cumulative mean of recent observations

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

My dataset has as features: players IDs, weeks and points.

I want to calculate the mean of points for previous weeks, but not all past weeks, just to the last 5 or less (if the current week is smaller than 5).

Example: For player_id = 5, week = 7, the result will be the average of POINTS for player_id = 5 and weeks 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

The following code already does the average for all previous week, so I need an adaptation to make it for just 5 previous week.

```
player_id<-c(rep(1,30),rep(2,30),rep(3,30),rep(4,30),rep(5,30))
week<-1:30
points<-round(runif(150,1,10),0) 
mydata<- data.frame(player_id=player_id,week=rep(week,5),points)


mydata<-mydata %>% 
        group_by(player_id) %>%    # the group to perform the stat on
        arrange(week) %>%          # order the weeks within each group
        mutate(previous_mean = cummean(points) ) %>% # for each week get the 
cumulative mean
        mutate(previous_mean = lag(previous_mean) ) %>% # shift cumulative 
mean back one week
        arrange(player_id) # sort by player_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HAVB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527951/havb)'s approach is great, but depending on what you want, here is another. This approach is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4422414/8386140) to a different question, but changed for your circumstances:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
# set the seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)
player_id<-c(rep(1,30),rep(2,30),rep(3,30),rep(4,30),rep(5,30))
week<-1:30
points<-round(runif(150,1,10),0) 
mydata<- data.frame(player_id=player_id,week=rep(week,5),points)

roll_mean <- function(x, k) {
    result <- rollapplyr(x, k, mean, partial=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
    result[is.nan(result)] <- NA
    return( result )
}

mydata<- data.frame(player_id=player_id,week=rep(week,5),points)

mydata<-mydata %>% 
    group_by(player_id) %>%
    arrange(week) %>%
    mutate(rolling_mean = roll_mean(x=lag(points), k=5) ) %>%
    arrange(player_id)
```

Then we can look at a subset to show it worked:

```
mydata[mydata$player_id %in% 1:2 & mydata$week %in% 1:6, ]
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   player_id [2]
   player_id  week points rolling_mean
       <dbl> <int>  <dbl>        <dbl>
 1         1     1      4           NA
 2         1     2      8     4.000000
 3         1     3      5     6.000000
 4         1     4      9     5.666667
 5         1     5      9     6.500000
 6         1     6      1     7.000000
 7         2     1     10           NA
 8         2     2      9    10.000000
 9         2     3      7     9.500000
10         2     4      8     8.666667
11         2     5      1     8.500000
12         2     6      5     7.000000
```

So we can see at each time *t*, `rolling_mean` for player *i* will be the mean of the `points` observations for player *i* at times {*t* - 1, ..., min(1, *t* - 5)}.

Comment: How could I use this approach but ignoring the current week in the rolling mean? Because I will use the rolling mean as a predictor to points, so I cannot consider it in the same row. Thanks @duckmayr

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` to select just the last 5 weeks for each group. Try this:

```
player_id<-c(rep(1,30),rep(2,30),rep(3,30),rep(4,30),rep(5,30))
week<-1:30
points<-round(runif(150,1,10),0) 
mydata<- data.frame(player_id=player_id,week=rep(week,5),points)

library(dplyr)

mydata <- mydata %>% 
    group_by(player_id) %>%    # the group to perform the stat on
    arrange(week) %>% # order the weeks within each group
    slice( (n()-4):n() ) %>%  # "slice" the last 5 rows (weeks) of every group
    mutate(previous_mean = cummean(points) ) %>% # for each week get the cumulative mean
mutate(previous_mean = lag(previous_mean) ) %>% # shift cumulative mean back one week
arrange(player_id) # sort by player_id
```

The line

```
slice( (n()-4):n() )
```

selects rows within the range [(last row - 4) : last row], for each group

EDIT: To avoid trouble when the current week is less than 5, use an `ifelse` statement to validate:

```
mydata %>% 
    group_by(player_id) %>%    # the group to perform the stat on
    arrange(week) %>% # order the weeks within each group
    slice(ifelse(n() < 5, 1:n(), n()-4):n()) %>%  # "slice" the last 5 rows (weeks) of every group
    mutate(previous_mean = cummean(points) ) %>% # for each week get the cumulative mean
    mutate(previous_mean = lag(previous_mean) ) %>% # shift cumulative mean back one week
    arrange(player_id) # sort by player_id
```

Comment: I really liked your approach, but it just gives me the result for week 26 till 30...

Comment: It's intentional, I interpreted the problem as needing to keep only the last 5 weeks per player (ie, some players' didn't play every week, so individual sets for "last 5 appearances" will vary). Now I see what you actually needed! Luckily @duckmayr 's answer does the trick.